# Can I use Fitnesse on a project with a mix of 32 bit and 64 bit dlls?

Tags: .net, fitnesse

I am currently using Fitnesse server release 20111026 to test against a 64 bit project that contains references to some DLLs of .NET projects that were compiled as 64 bit and some that were compiled x86. Visual studio doesn't have an issue with this, however when I add the !path referencing the dll that was built using x86 I get the following message from Fitnesse:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyDLL.DLL' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.

Fitnesse runner is build on AnyCPU, you should patch one to x86, thru following command

```
corflags runner.exe /32BIT+
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383138/BadImageFormatException-x86-i-x64) is how to check runner platform